# Como chamar o PDO em arquivo distintos do sistema?

Tags: php, pdo

Estou com um problema de programação no qual coloco minha conexão do tipo PDO no header e preciso que `$pdo` seja chamado em qualquer outro arquivo do sistema. Exemplo:

> header.php

```
<?php require("configs/conexao.php"); ?>
```

> index.php

```
<?php 

     require("header.php");
     // todo o conteúdo
     require("footer.php");

?>
```

> footer.php

```
<?php 

     $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");

?>
```

Meu `conexao.php` é este: **[PDO](http://pastebin.com/MU5EmEBK)**

Podemos reparar que chamei a conexão PDO no header porque este arquivo estará presente em todas as páginas do sistema e quero poder fazer um ***select*** no footer pois existe a necessidade de se chamar alguma informação ali.

Eu imaginava que o fato dos ***requires*** ligarem um arquivo ao outro faria com que o `$pdo` viajasse até o footer mas não é o que acontece. Ai eu tenho que chamar o arquivo ***conexao.php*** no footer, o que eu imagino que se trate de ***POG***.

Como poderei então inserir o arquivo de conexão no header e chamar o `$pdo` no footer ou em qualquer outro arquivo caso exista a necessidade?

> Atualização

- Este é o único arquivo que eu uso para me conectar a todo o sistema, então a conexão não está sendo fechada. Vou ativar os erros do PHP.

Comment: Aparentemente isso deveria funcionar. Pode ser que os includes não funcionem em determinada página por conta de caminhos relativos (e você esteja com os avisos e erros desligados); pode ser que tenha algo em seu código fechando a conexão ou impedindo que novas queries sejam executadas; podem ser várias coisas, acho difícil responder com certeza só com as informações que você postou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um teste aqui e funcionou perfeitamente. Tente executar esses scripts abaixo:

Banco:

```
<?php

try {
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=loja;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';

    $objDb = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $objDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo   $e->getMessage();
}
```

header.php

```
 <?php require("banco/conexaoPDO.php");

    ?>
 <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title></title>
    </head>
```

footer.php

```
<?php

 $sql = "SELECT name FROM products"; 

   $result = $objDb->query($sql);

   if (!$result) {
        throw new PDOException('The execute massage failed ');
    }

  $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $items = $result->fetchAll();

    foreach ( $items as  $item)
         echo "<br>" . $item['name'] . "<br>";
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <?php  
    require("header.php");
    ?>
    <body>

    </body>
     <?php require("footer.php");
      ?>
</html>
```